# Unable to get single property from response Angular 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, model-view-controller, typescript

I want to access the property 'Status' from the controller and simply do some operations but I am unable to get this property and do any further operation. I am sharing my code below:

TasksController:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetTasks()
{
   var q = (from a in db.Tsk
         join b in db.TType on a.TaskTypeID equals b.TaskTypeID
         join c in db.Prior on a.PriorityID equals c.PriorityID
         join d in db.Usr on a.AssignedTo equals d.Employees.EmpName
         select new
         {
          a.TaskID,
          a.TaskCode,
          a.AssignedTo,
          a.Date,
          a.DueDate,
          a.Status,
          a.Reply,
          a.PriorityID,
          a.TaskTypeID,
          b.TaskType,
          c.Priorities,
          d.Login
         }).ToList().Skip(1).AsEnumerable();
      db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

AppService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

@Injectable()

export class AppService {
constructor(private _http: Http) { }

//Task Register
getFTRs(c: string) {
return this._http.get('Tasks/GetTasks').map(res => res.json().filter(a => a.Login === c));
}
}
```

HomeComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../_services/index';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';
import { LoginComponent } from '../login/index';
import { User, TaskRegisters } from '../contract';
import { Message } from '../message';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html',
    providers: [LoginComponent]
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    users: User[];
    tasks: string;
    msgs: Message[] = [];
    curr: any;
    constructor(private userService: AuthenticationService,
        private Tsk: AppService,
        private Log: LoginComponent) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        debugger;
        this.curr = localStorage.getItem('currentUser').slice(1);
        this.Tsk.getFTRs(this.curr).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.tasks = res.Status,
                    error => console.log(error) 
            });
        if (this.tasks) {
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Task Assigned', detail: 'A new task has been assigned to you' })
        }
    }
}
```

Status is a boolean and if boolean is `true`, I want to push the message in msgs array. I am unable to get the value of Status and store it in tasks variable of home component. Whenever I run the program it shows this.tasks as undefined thus making and comparison impossible. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 this.Tsk.getFTRs(this.curr).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.tasks = res.Status,
                    error => console.log(error) 
            });
        if (this.tasks) {
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Task Assigned', detail: 'A new task has been assigned to you' })
        }
```

to

```
 this.Tsk.getFTRs(this.curr).subscribe(
            (res) => {
                console.log(res); //What does this print?
                this.tasks = res.Status;
                console.log(this.tasks); //What does this print?
                if (this.tasks) {
                      this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Task Assigned', detail: 'A new task has been assigned to you' })
                }
            },
            (error) => {console.log(error);}
   );
```

Since you're assingning `this.tasks` inside `getFRSs'` callback which is **async**, by the time you are using it below in the `if` statement it is `undefined`.

Comment: this.tasks is still undefined

Comment: @RehanSiddiqui what does `console.log(res);` print inside subscribe? Check my updated answer.

Comment: It logs an [Object] containing AssignedTo:"Jahangir"
Date:"/Date(1480705200000)/"
DueDate:"/Date(1481137200000)/"
Login:"jahangir"
Priorities:"Urgent"
PriorityID:2
Reply:false
Status:true
TaskCode:"03/2"
TaskID:4
TaskType:"Individual"
TaskTypeID:1

Comment: Can you repeat this for `this.tasks` under it ? As I've updated it in my answer.

Comment: check my answer on this post. It pushes the notification now when Status is true.

Answer (score 0):

Since this.tasks is available to me now after the edit of @echonax I did this to make it work!

```
ngOnInit() {
        debugger;
        this.curr = localStorage.getItem('currentUser').slice(1);
        this.Tsk.getFTRs(this.curr).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.tasks = res;
                for (let i = 0; i < this.tasks.length; i++){
                    if (this.tasks[i].Status) {
                        this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Task Assigned', detail: 'A new task has been assigned to you' })
                    }
                }
            },
            error => console.log(error)
        )}
```